# Printing to a Windows 7 incompatible printer shared on supported Windows XP machine

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have an HP Laserjet 1500 that is supported by Windows XP, but not supported by Windows-7. I want to print from my 7 machine(s) to my XP machine on this printer. Is there some sort of way to send a generic job (like sending raw postscript or something) to the XP machine, which will then print it with the proper drivers? Is there a virtual printer that has drivers for both XP and 7 that will just re-print it on the XP machine using the real printer?

Comment: Assuming this is the color Laserjet 1500, have you simply tried the Color Laserjet 2500 drivers?  HP printers are usually easy, can substitute similar and lower-level drivers (that is, earlier or more basic printers) most of the time.  There are also lots of alternatives if you only want to print B/W, since drivers for, say, the HP Laserjet 4 tend to work with almost every HP laser printer out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the HOWTO you need:
http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSPSprinter/GSPSprinter.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I haven't tested it yet, but I'm hopeful, thanks!